# Spliting the String except last word

Tags: javascript, java

i need to split this string

```
"5294-Process Done-03-12-2014 09:22:20-20-4537-Active-No-61240-ADBC DEF-NE IHK SMR-MCF-FMAP"
```

to

```
"5294,Process Done,03-12-2014 09:22:20,20,4537,Active,No,61240,ADBC DEF-NE IHK SMR-MCF-FMAP".
```

Thanks for Helping

Comment: You just got my permission. :D Do it right away.

Comment: Split on - then reconstruct the date and letters. Or use a regex to grab the date and letters first, remove them from string, then split. If the 4digit numebrs are always 4 digits long, you could probably do some magic with substring and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="5294-Process Done-03-12-2014 09:22:20-20-4537-Active-No-61240-ADBC DEF-NE IHK SMR-MCF-FMAP";
    String[] v1= s.substring(0, 18).split("-");
    String s1=s.substring(19, 37);
    String[] v2= s.substring(38, 61).split("-");
    String s2=s.substring(62, s.length()-1);
    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String a:v1){
        lst.add(a);
    }
    lst.add(s1);
    for(String b:v2){
        lst.add(b);
    }
    lst.add(s2);
    System.out.println(lst.toString());
```

Comment: funny.. interesting.. you have not failed :)